# Uploading a file through selenium but file input element is hidden

Tags: file-upload, selenium, hidden-field

I am trying to upload a file using Selenium but my input file element is hidden.

My hidden HTML is:

```
<input id="yui_3_9_0pr3_1_1361897421363_2239" type="file" style="visibility:hidden; width:0px; height: 0px;" multiple="" accept="">
```

and the select file button HTML is:

```
<button id="yui_3_9_0pr3_1_1361897421363_2242" class="yui3-button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Select Files" role="button" type="button" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Select Files</button>
```

I tried the same thing using `JavascriptExecutor` which you suggested but it still gives an exception `ElementNotVisible: Element is not currently visible`.

This is my code:

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//@input[@type='file']));
System.out.println("h14");
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, fileInput);
System.out.println("h15");
LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
String path = "//Users//pdua//Desktop//images.jpeg";

// File f = detector.getLocalFile(path);
//((RemoteWebElement)fileInput).setFileDetector(detector);
System.out.println("h16");

//fileInput.sendKeys(f.getAbsolutePath());
fileInput.sendKeys(path);
```

The XPath of the hidden input file element is `//input[@type='file']`. Not sure if that is right or not!

Comment: how would you manually make it visible?

Comment: Nice question from niharika (so for example if you need to hover over a menu in order to make it visible manually --> you need to emulate the same behavior via selenium as well)..I will add TRY CSS selector instead of xpath

Comment: the xpath(//@input[@type='file']) is working for me in chrome, but in firefox and safari it complains that the element isn't visible. did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium will not interact with element if it is not visible and/or displayed. This could be caused by variety of the settings:

- `visibility=hidden`;
- `display=none`;
- `height=0` or `width=0`;
- <strike>position outside of displayable coordinate (e.g. left=-1)</strike>

In your code you show `height` and `width` equal to 0, but only reset `height`. Try following JS:

```
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='1'; arguments[0].style.width='1'; "
            + "arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
```

Additionally, inspect the `input[@type='file']` element in browser to check if there are any other styles or classes applied to it that can effect visibility. In my case, there was a class applied to `button` wrapping `input[@type='file']` element, setting `display=none;`.

**NOTE:** When changing the element visibility, the test is modifying the application under the test. It is an intrusive behaviour not recommended for the tests.

**UPDATE:** It appears element outside of the screen (e.g. `left=-1200`) is reported not displayed in Selenium, but it does not prevent Selenium to execute `sendKeys()` method on it. The method has no return type and does not through exception in this case.