# Selenium Hidden File upload in Drag Drop UI

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add image in the following input using selenium web-driver.

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="dz-hidden-input" accept="image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,application/zip" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

When used sendKeys it gives ElementNotVisible: Element is not currently visible as visibility is hidden.

Tried to execute using Java script set value it gave web-driver exception saying "The operation is insecure."

I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5064) closed issue similar to mine.

Tried :

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';",fileInput);

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='block';", fileInput);
```

To enable the visibility but send keys failed with same error.

I found similar question [Uploading a file through selenium but file input element is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095601/uploading-a-file-through-selenium-but-file-input-element-is-hidden) but my element never becomes visible.

I tried with selenium IDE its working with type command.

Please let me know if any one has faced same issue and how it got fixed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Try to set Opacity for the Input element to 1 and then use SendKeys to provide file path. Opacity can be set using following code:

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';",fileInput);
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.height='200px';",fileInput);   
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].style.width='200px';",fileInput);
```

And then execute sendKeys method.

Lemme if that helps!

Comment: I tried this but not working : INFO - Done: [execute script: arguments[0].style.opacity='1';, [[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (62d69895-4ab1-4598-b552-425ea7c13e77)] -> xpath: //input[@type='file'][1]]]]
INFO - Executing: [send keys: 50 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (62d69895-4ab1-4598-b552-425ea7c13e77)] -> xpath: //input[@type='file'][1]], [/data1/vishal/svn/9.0.0/automation/selenium/client/dataupload//content_library//images//nature.gif]])
WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having problems targeting dz-hidden-input with multiple dropzones on one page, you should do this:

```
  init: function() {
    this.hiddenFileInput.className = "dz-hidden-input dz-hidden-input-one";
  }
```

Then you can target the hidden input with $(".dz-hidden-input-one")